# Align elements both leading and trailing in same container, without stretching it, in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment, chat

I'm trying to build a simple chat with a design like the most usual messengers.

A message consists of a user name (if not your own message), the message itself and a timestamp.

I want the width of a message to be determined by the widest child element (most likely the message, but in rare cases maybe the user name or timestamp).

I also want the user name and message to be **aligned leading/left** and the timestamp to be **aligned trailing/right**, just like group chats in WhatsApp, Signal or the likes..

I tried weird amounts of H/V/Z-Stacks, which lead to weird happenings. I also tried both adding Spacers and `maxLength = .infinity`, which lead to the message stretching to the far right with lots of empty space.

My current code has all elements aligned centered:

[image: How it's looking right now]

And this is what I want:

[image: How I want it]

This code is only for the comment, which itself is embedded into a ScrollView/VStack for each one.

```
HStack() {
    if comment.author?.id == currentUserId {
        Spacer()
            .frame(width: 50)
        Spacer()
    }
    VStack(spacing: 3) {
        if comment.author?.id != currentUserId {
            Text("Test User")
                .font(.body)
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                .border(.red)
        }
        Text("Test message content")
            .frame(alignment: .leading)
            .border(.red)
        Text(date)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .frame(alignment: .trailing)
            .border(.red)
    }
    .border(.green)
    .padding(10)
    .background(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(10)
    if comment.author?.id != currentUserId {
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
            .frame(width: 50)
    }
}
```

Also I thought the double Spacers on the left or right side looked kinda weird. I tried using `.frame(minWidth: 50)`, which ended up way too wide and pushes even a small message like the one on the image into a second line.

I'm happy for any ideas for these problems, but I'm trying to go for a simple solution and no complex calculations with alignmentGuides or GeometryReader or similar.

Comment: This is kind of the thing that GeometryReader was made for... without hard-coding values, there isn't really a dynamic way to do this without something like a Geometry reader. Also, try to make a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time!

Comment: Since we have the possibility to align all elements to either direction, I expected there to be a simple solution for aligning them independently to both directions. But I guess I might have to try the GeometryReader for it.

Also I edited the code a little to remove some unnecessary stuff, but in the past I've been told to remove fewer code, cause the problem could be lying there.

Answer (score 3):

`.frame` allows you to specify the alignment.

So you could just make the `VStack` leading and then use `.frame` on the last element with `alignment: .trailing`. Keep in mind that the `View` will then grow to its available space. If you want to prevent that, just add `.fixedSize()` (or `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)`) to the parent view.

[image]

```swift
GroupBox {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Test User")
        
        Text("Test Message Content")
        
        Text("9.5.2022, 19:31")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    }
    .fixedSize()
}
```

or if you want to keep the `VStack` on the default alignment

```swift
GroupBox {
    VStack {
        Text("Test User")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
        Text("Test Message Content")
        
        Text("9.5.2022, 19:31")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    }
    .fixedSize()
}
```

but it also works using a `HStack` + `Spacer`

```swift
GroupBox {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Test User")
        
        Text("Test Message Content")
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("9.5.2022, 19:31")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
    .fixedSize()
}
```

Comment: These look pretty good at first when inserted into my code. But as soon as the message gets longer, it stretches so wide that it leaves the screen on both sides. This seems to be due to `fixedSize()`, because without it that doesn't happen (but then the message stretches the full screen again in all cases)